# Error when running stack build language-plutus-core on Windows 8

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack, plutus

When I ran the command `stack build language-plutus-core` I received the following error:

```
--  While building custom Setup.hs for package cryptonite-openssl-0.7 using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6
.4.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\e626a42b configure --with-ghc=C:\Users...
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: C:\Projects\2019-08-07-Plutus\plutus-master\.stac
k-work\logs\cryptonite-openssl-0.7.log

    Configuring cryptonite-openssl-0.7...
    Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.4.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign  libraries:
    * Missing (or bad) C libraries: eay32, ssl32
    This problem can usually be solved by installing the system packages that
    provide these libraries (you may need the "-dev" versions). If the libraries are already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where they are.
If the library files do exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
```

Anyone any idea how to fix this? Do i need to install eay32, ssl32 separately?

Answer (score 1):

Consider installing these packages using the bundled MSYS in your stack installation. First do `stack exec bash` to enter MSYS, then use the `pacman` in that MSYS environment.

The packages from the bundled `pacman` are from MinGW32, MinGW64 and MSYS2, so most of them (as far as I have used) should be prefixed with `mingw-w64-i686-` or `mingw-w64-x86_64-`. See [the official documentation for msys2](https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Using-packages) for detailed information.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use pacman to install eay32 and ssl32? None of the pacman commands I've used are working.

Comment: @user1023733 I checked using `pacman -Ss`, and it appears MSYS2 doesn’t come with EAY. Would need a more experienced MSYS2 person to confirm this though — maybe edit that tag into your question?

Comment: @Krantz Never thought of `stack exec bash` — thanks for that! I’ve always used `stack exec mintty`, which opens up a separate terminal emulator completely.